# Duration of System Update - Nexus 4 (after download) - 4.4.2 to 4.4.3?

Tags: updates, system

How long is it supposed to take to install the system update, I think from 4.4.2 to 4.4.3, on a Nexus 4?

I downloaded the 70 MB and after the phone restarted, it attempted to install the system update for the last 2+ hours. The progress bar starts, goes all the way to the end, the screen goes black for a split second and then the install screen appears again with the bar starting at the beginning again. The phone is not brand new anymore, but I would expect it to go faster.

If this is too long and maybe an error occurred, can I cancel the update process by pressing >Vol-Down + Power Button< without having to worry about an unusable phone afterwards?

Comment: Okay, I did the hard reboot (or however you call it), that did not change anything. So it wanted to boot, but then went back to installing the update (which is a very comprehensible behavior).

Comment: Sorry, the last comment was a bit overambitious. After rebooting the phone, the system update went through and the system is updated now. Interesting fix for this problem ;-)

Comment: As you managed to solve your issue: Could you post your solution as *answer*, so other users affected can identify it as being solved? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, after giving up on waiting more, I restarting the phone.

After reboot, the update started from where it was, and finished as originally intended.

To restart the phone, hold `Vol-Down + Power` for a few seconds.

Posting answer as the OP only posted solution in a comment.

Comment: Could not add the answer as I had not enough reputation points yet. But I could have done it in the meanwhile, that is true.

Comment: @Exocom Makes sense, it's easy to forgot that not everyone can post answers. Since we'd like to have the question answered, either accept my answer, or please consider coming back later when you have more rep. :)